# What causes the unusual high upload when connected to a VPN?

Tags: vpn, download, openvpn, bandwidth, upload

I've noticed an unusual high usage of my upload, whenever a download is running.

The upload is usually somewhere 5-10% of the download bandwidth usage.

I assume the VPN connection itself requires the upload for something, but I couldn't figure out what for.

OpenVPN 2.3.7 on Debian and the VPN tunnel uses UDP.

**edit** No torrents. 
e.g. If I download Kali Linux via the official host, I currently get 180-250 kB/s, the upload is ~50kB/s..

I've had cases where a HTTP/S download would get ~4MB/s and the upload maxed out my bandwidth with ~380kB/s..

Comment: What download protocol are you using? For example, BitTorrent seeds the blocks you've already downloaded even if you haven't finished downloading the torrent. So you're uploading chunks of the torrent to other people at the same time as you're downloading it from others.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but I'm not torrenting, normal http/s downloads

Comment: Your SERVER upload speed is the bottle neck

Comment: I doubt that a 1Gpbs Server is the bottleneck in a scenario where I reach my max. upload..

Answer (score 0):

On the benign side, you may have programs running hidden in the background. Check for programs doing stealth updating.

On the malignant side, using a VPN really does not protect from someone who already put some form of malicious spyware or RAT in your system. They can run innocuously while you use the internet and are becoming increasingly more common. It may be there for a while, but becomes obvious when the bandwidth is restricted like when using a VPN.

You can try to narrow down a reason for the ghost % usage by monitoring not just your running programs, but also the processes behind them; keeping an eye on your ports, knowing what is connecting to your computer not just what's going out.

Here's a list of free Network Analysis tools that might help:

http://www.gfi.com/blog/the-top-20-free-network-monitoring-and-analysis-tools-for-sys-admins/

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN does not require a high upload bandwidth when downloading.  (Its non-zero, but if you are downloading anything of a reasonable side, it should be way less then 1% unless you are running a stupidly small MTU.

As @Spiff said, if you are using Bittorrent, you are probably sharing file fragments - if you are using VPN its entirely possible that this process is working more effectively then before, as its easier for remote hosts to create incoming ports.

VPN does require a very small amount of bandwidth when operating to set up and keep the tunnel open - likewise when downloading you also need to send acknowledgement packets back - but these packets are very small.